# mount hardware raid disk 1 with one disk and no hardware raid controler

Tags: raid, hard-drive, lsi

I have one of two raid disk (from LSI raid card)

There is a way to mount it in a PC and access to the disk without the raid card?

Maybe mounting or skipping the first bytes!?

Thanks in advance.

Peter.

Comment: Have you tried just plugging it in?

Answer (score 0):

There is [dmraid](http://people.redhat.com/~heinzm/sw/dmraid/) which supports one kind of LSI raid (MegaRAID), but they do have more IIRC so it might not work for you :(